# automatically run ssh-copy-id when public key not available remotely

Tags: ssh

Assume I have a bunch of remote servers into which i'd like to be able to ssh into. In the `~/.ssh/config` something like

```
Host ManyHosts-*
    IdentityFile /home/pseyfert/.ssh/id_for_ManyHosts
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PreferredAuthentications publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
```

So when I have an ssh agent running, not yet run `ssh-add`, and connect to a host that already has my public key, i would

- run `ssh ManyHosts-001`
- be asked for my key's passphrase
- get connected to `ManyHosts-001`
- subsequent connections to hosts that already have my public key would skip the passphrase step since the ssh-agent already has the key.

Note how this is more convenient than

- run `ssh ManyHosts-001`
- notice the passphrase prompt
- hit `^C`
- run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_for_ManyHosts`
- type passphrase
- run `ssh ManyHosts-001`

When connecting to a host that doesn't have my public key, the workflow usually turns into

- run `ssh ManyHosts-099`
- notice the password prompt
- hit `^C`
- run `ssh-copy-id ManyHosts-099`
- type the password
- run `ssh ManyHosts-099` to connect.

I'm wondering if there is an automation for `ssh-copy-id` that would have the following usage pattern

- run `ssh ManyHosts-099`
- public key not available, get a password prompt
- type password
- connection gets established, public key is copied to host, I get a shell prompt on the host.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` checks if the key exists on the remote host. So, perhaps you could unconditionally run `ssh-copy-id` before `ssh`.

Comment: Based on the previous comment i tried (was not implied, that was my silly addition) `match Host ... exec "ssh-copy-id %h"` before my `Host` line in `.ssh/config`. Turns out that's very silly because it recursively starts ssh-copy-id over and over, each one opening the next in an attempt to establish a connection to copy the key. so hooking the unconditional ssh-copy-id into .ssh/config is not how to implement berndbausch's suggestion.